# Posting to LiveData from Coroutine to Update UI even if LiveData Will Only Update Once

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

In my ViewModel's constructor, I immediately launch a coroutine to make a one time network call.  To update the UI based on the result of this network call, I post updates to a few LiveData variables in my ViewModel. These LiveData variables are, in turn, observed by a fragment which then make the necessary UI updates.

What I'm wondering is if this is a valid way to make UI updates from a coroutine. As I mentioned earlier, the network request is only a one time thing done upon initialization, and so the LiveData variables will never be updated more than once. Is it then wasteful to set up observers in my fragment since I know for a fact they will only be called once? If so, what would be a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it then wasteful to set up observers in my fragment since I know for a fact they will only be called once?

They may be called more than once.

Primarily, `LiveData` is a value holder. And, specifically, by having `LiveData` in a `ViewModel`, you retain the `LiveData` and the held values across configuration changes (screen rotations, dark mode switch, etc.).

So, the flow may wind up being:

- Your fragment is created
- Your viewmodel is created and you kick off the network I/O
- Your fragment instantiates its UI
- Your fragment observes the `LiveData`
- Your coroutine completes and your viewmodel updates the `LiveData`
- Your fragment receives the value from the `LiveData` and updates the UI
- The user twists her wrist and rotates the screen
- Your fragment is destroyed
- Your replacement fragment is created
- Your viewmodel *is retained*, and your replacement fragment gets that same viewmodel with the same `LiveData`
- Your replacement fragment instantiates its UI
- Your replacement fragment observes the `LiveData`
- Your replacement fragment receives the value from the `LiveData` and updates the UI

So, what you are describing is generally reasonable.